# Почему новый TextView криво отображается в ListView при использовании ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview

Сделал так,чтоб каждое входящее сообщение записывалось в свой TextView.

Этот метод вызывается в потоке.

```
public void inputMessage(){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
            String stringInputMessage;
            while (true){
                if ((stringInputMessage = dataInputStream.readUTF()) != null){
                    final String finalStringInputMessage = stringInputMessage;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TextView textViewMessage = createTextView();
                            textViewMessage.setText(finalStringInputMessage);
                            listMessage.add(textViewMessage);
                            listViewMessage.setAdapter(arrayAdapterMessage);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Этот отдельно от  потока.

```
private TextView createTextView() {
    textViewMessage = new TextView(this);
    return textViewMessage;
}
```

В конечном итоге получается такая картина.
[image]

Элементы добавляются, но текста на них нет.

Comment: Вы не предоставили кода адаптера. И не очень понятно что вы хотите, что делаете и что получается. Попробуйте добавить конкретики и более точный формулировок.

Comment: Заменил TextView на String.

Comment: Яснее не стало. Может там у вас список в ScrollView лежит?..

Comment: я думаю, вам нужно почитать любой урок про ListView. Все стразу станет ясно.

Comment: Очевидно, вы в адаптер в качестве данных передаете не сам текст, который нужно отобразить, а какую то ссылку на виджет `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

При получении нового сообщения, не надо заново устанавливать адаптер, используйте adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Без кода адаптера сложно понять, почему у вас отображается ссылка на TextView, а не его значение. Предполагаю, что у вас код такого плана:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
   TextView textView = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
   textView.setText(listMessage.get(position));
   ...
}
```

а надо:

```
textView.setText(listMessage.get(position).getText());
```